# How to use friendly_id to find product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I installed `friendly_id` according to the instructions. And use it for products.
For `show` i use:

```rb
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

And it works.
But I have a couple of question, on its use for other controllers.
In `cart_item_controller` i use:

```rb
@cart_item = current_user.cart.cart_items.find_by(product_id: params[:product_id])
```

I changed it to:

```rb
@cart_item = current_user.cart.cart_items.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

But i get error

```
undefined method `friendly' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> Did you mean? friendly_id?
```

How do I properly replace this so that it works?
Also, for comments i use:

```rb
  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
```

I tried replacing this with:

```rb
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

But getting an error:

```
Couldn't find Product without an ID
```

Comment: I would only use friendly id where you actually need it for vanity urls. Like say `/users/bob` or  `/products/iphone6`. Its not meant to replace the finders everywhere in your application as a straight primary key look is much faster than `WHERE  id = ? OR slug = ?`. It gets even more messy if you have slug history as then it has to join a seperate table as well.

Comment: @max This is my homework :) I must do it :)

Comment: Then you would need to do something like `current_user.cart.cart_items.find_by(product_id: Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id]))`.

Comment: "Couldn't find Product without an ID" means that `params[:product_id]`is nil and really has nothing to do with friendly id.